# Toilet Connector Hose Removal

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, toilet

I'm replacing the toilet connector hose because there's a leak from the bowl. I've tried to remove the old connector hose but the metal piece in the pic will not detach. It spins when I use a steel adjustable wrench but no movement otherwise.Any ideas on how to get it off?[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the "old days" there were a ton of stop valves installed that had the flex supply line *integrated into the valve*, i.e. all one piece. Thankfully, they started disappearing from the market. Now we are seeing Chivese stop valves with integrated flex supply; I suspect yours might be one of those.

I suspect that to replace your flex you will need to replace both the *valve* and the flex. However, you say there is "a leak from the bowl", which shouldn't have anything to do with the supply flex because the supply flex goes to the *tank* fill valve, not the bowl.

Comment: In other words, unscrew the other end of that supply hose where it attaches to the tank.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, actually I did not mean that at all, but you may have the answer the OP needs. Why disconnect at the valve anyway? You should post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I misspoke. The part of the hose that connects to the tank is leaking. It's not water tight anymore. It sprays water. I thought I could just add plumber's tape to stop the leak but replacing the hose with valve might be better. We're working on selling the house anyway.